# Swift 3 Extracting similar objects

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have an `array` of `array`s containg `int`, so `let pairs:[[Int]]`.

I am looking for an elegant way to extract similar elements.

For example my pairs variable could contain something like: `[ [1,2], [4,6], [1,2] ]`

I would like to extract any array that occurs more than once like `[1,2]`.
In the example `[ [1,2], [4,6], [1,2], [3,7], [4,6] ]` I would like to extract both `[1,2]` and `[4,6]`.

This seemed trivial at first, but every go I had at it became very cumbersome with many "helper arrays" and nested "for loops". There surely is a simpler way in Swift, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here the way using just one helper Dictionary and one loop:

```
let pairs = [[1,2], [4,6], [1,2]] // The original array
var pairCount = [NSArray : Int]() // This is helper dictionary. The key is the array, the value is - how much time it appears in the source array. I use NSArray because swift array does not conform to Hashable protocol.
var newPairs = [[Int]]()

for pair in pairs { // Iterate over our pairs
    var count: Int = pairCount[pair as NSArray] ?? 0 // If we already have a pair in our dictionary get count of it in array otherwise het 0

    count += 1 // increase counter

    pairCount[pair as NSArray] = count // save in dictionary
}

let pairsWithCountMoreThanOne = pairCount.flatMap({$1 > 1 ? $0 : nil}) // here we get the result

for pair in pairsWithCountMoreThanOne { // Just print it
    print("\(pair)")
}
```

This code may not be memory efficient for large arrays or large objects but it is really trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below :

```
let pairs = [ [1,2], [4,6], [1,2], [3,7], [4,6], [3,5], [4,6] ]
var repeats = [[Int]]()

pairs.forEach { (i) in
    let count = (pairs.filter{ return $0 == i }).count
    if count > 1 {
        if !repeats.contains(where: { (pair) -> Bool in
            return pair == i
        }) {
            repeats.append(i)
        }
    }
}
print(repeats) // Output is : [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
```